# Understand the word sense disambiguation data set format

Tags: dataset, word-sense-disambiguation

I am trying to evaluate a WSD model using well-known WSD data set (SemEval, SensEval). But I am don't understand the format of the gold key text file.

**seneval3.gold.key.txt**

```
d000.s000.t000 man%1:18:00::
d000.s000.t001 say%2:32:01::
d000.s001.t000 peer%2:39:00::
d000.s001.t001 companion%1:18:00::
d000.s001.t002 bleary%5:00:00:indistinct:00
d000.s001.t003 eye%1:08:00::
d000.s002.t000 have%2:40:00::
d000.s002.t001 ready%5:00:01:available:00
d000.s002.t002 answer%1:04:00::
d000.s002.t003 much%3:00:00::
d000.s002.t004 surprise%1:12:00::
d000.s002.t005 fit%1:26:00::
d000.s002.t006 coughing%1:26:00::
d000.s003.t000 man%1:18:00::
d000.s003.t001 drunk%3:00:00::
d000.s003.t002 crazy%5:00:00:insane:00
d000.s004.t000 newfound%5:00:00:new:00
```

I know that in the first line `d000.s000.t000` talking about the document #0 sentence #0 token #0 by looking at the data file.

**senseval3.data.xml**

```
<sentence id="d000.s000">
    <wf lemma="that" pos="DET">That</wf>
    <wf lemma="&apos;" pos="VERB">&apos;s</wf>
    <wf lemma="what" pos="PRON">what</wf>
    <wf lemma="the" pos="DET">the</wf>
    <instance id="d000.s000.t000" lemma="man" pos="NOUN">man</instance>
    <wf lemma="have" pos="VERB">had</wf>
    <instance id="d000.s000.t001" lemma="say" pos="VERB">said</instance>
    <wf lemma="." pos=".">.</wf>
</sentence>
```

But I don't know what is meant after `%`, for example `1:18:00::` for lemma man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is composed based on the comment given for this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110269/senseval-2-dataset-format/18649706?noredirect=1#comment118069770_18649706).

The number sequence followed by `%` is the lex_index. Lex index composed as follows.

`ss_type:lex_filenum:lex_id:head_word:head_id`

More information is in the WordNet [documentation](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/senseidx5wn).